# How to apply Theme.Wallpaper at runtime on android?

Tags: android, themes

I use following code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

But it does nothing!

How can I apply Theme.Wallpaper at runtime on android?

Comment: not sure if it would matter but have you tried calling setContentView first?

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you call the `setTheme()` method even before the call to the constructor of your parent class (i.e. before `super.onCreate(...)`).

The following works for me:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

However, it's not perfect: when launching the activity, the shown animation still belongs to the default theme -> a black screen fades in. After the animation finishes, the wallpaper theme is shown.

If you want to have a wallpaper-themed fade-in animation, you have to use the declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml